# Delete Instance button on Azure dashboard is gone ! Unable to delete staging instance

Tags: azure

Yesterday I uploaded a new deployement on staging instance, VIP swapped, all good, then when I wanted to delete staging instances like usual... I didn't see any delete button anymore on the page CLOUD SERVCIES > INSTANCES > STAGING of the dashboard. And today still no button.

No way to contact MS withou paying for a premium support I will use one time only.
Well that's clever from MS... I mean... I'm paying the staging instance even if it does not serve any purpose.

Tried to use REST API but I can't get the authorized access.

Anyway, I do need this delete button back on staging instances !
Anyone ?

Comment: Billing support is free, in case you're concerned about overpaying due to difficulty removing staging instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, looks like Azure Cmdlets is the only option right now (the delete button is no longer showed in the management portal).

```
Remove-AzureDeployment [-ServiceName] <String> [-Slot] <String>
Remove-AzureDeployment -ServiceName <String> -Slot Staging
```

Answer (score 16):

Click on "Dashboard" and then you should see the "DELETE" button in the bottom application bar.  Hovering over "DELETE" should bring up a menu to delete the production or staging deployment (or the cloud service itself).

[image]

Comment: Sure, been using Azure since almost 2 years, been updloading, swapping, deleting hundread of times, I know how dashboard works, let me put this simply : THERE IS NO MORE DELETE BUTTON ON MY INSTANCES DASHBOARD

Comment: @JérômeTarere - no need to be hostile, yelling through all-caps. That's a fine way to not get help around here. I see the trashcan-shaped delete button just fine, as of 30 seconds ago. Maybe a browser issue?

Comment: Yes really sorry about the tone, but this is a big issue for me around production mode so i get a little stressed. Tried any browser, no delete button. I guess i have to find a way to contact Microsoft.

Comment: I ended up digging on Powershell Cmdlet to delete the staging, I hope I'll see this delete button back some day

Comment: I suggested the "Dashboard" tab because the original question explicitly stated looking at the "Instances" area.  The Delete (trash can icon) isn't under the "Instances" tab.

Comment: The Delete button exists in old Portal as of 8-Jun-2015, added picture for reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that from the UI as well by clicking on the "Delete" button on the root of the cloud service blade "Overview" this will give you the option to delete the entire cloud service or a specific deployment

[image: Delete deployment illustration in the new Azure Portal]